# Smart quotes in ArcGIS (titles, legends)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, font

Is there a way to ask ArcMap to use "smart quotes" in map titles, legends, etc.? This is what I've currently got on my map:

[image: title screenshot showing dumb (non-curly) quotes]

I'd like the quotation marks and apostrophe to be curved instead. Pretty cartography includes good font choices, and smart quotes look nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this and this seems to work, using your number pad try:

`alt + 0146` for the curly apostrophe `’`

`alt + 0147` for the opening curly quote `“`

`alt + 0148` for the closing curly quote `”`

Alternatively, you may want to download some [custom fonts](http://www.dafont.com/) that default to curly over straight. Looks like straight quotes are something window's does by [default as well.](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)

Comment: That's faster than the workaround I had thought of (copy and paste from the smart quotes Wikipedia page!)

Comment: Yeah alt codes are handy sometimes! I'm definitely guilty of using your method, especially for complicated formulas.